# Does Firebase Realtime Database have Free Unlimited reads and writes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

Does anyone know if Firebase Realtime Database have free unlimited writes? 
I don't see a pricing for writes or reads on Googles Firebase page. If so wouldnt it be much cheaper than Firestore if someone isnt expecting more than 10,000 on simultaneously?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Answer (score 0):

The way data is stored and retrieved with Realtime Database vs. Firestore are very different. The concept of reads/writes doesn't exist as it does in Firestore. Technically you are billed using a different set of metrics, so I would look into those metrics and how your application will act with regard to them.